# A lot of options in Boostrap selectpicker make it blank

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using js with bootstrap 1.13.9, my problem is: I have a selectpicker with more than 500 options, and if I go to the last item, it doesn't show it.

ex in the img,

Ps. look at the ul tag's style, the margin from top/bottom, it change from 68000px to 0px with just 1 scroll

[Option before the last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7j1x.png)

[Last option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkXrw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Use select2 instead bootstrap-selectpicker